# c++ call constructor of extended class stored in base class variable without knowing extended class

Tags: c++, class, templates, pointers, extending-classes

I am currently programming something where I hit this problem:

I have a `Scene` class and a `MainScene` class:

```
class Scene{
    Scene();
}

class MainScene : public Scene{
    MainScene();
}
```

And what I want to do is keep track of a list of scenes like this:

```
std::map<std::string, Scene*> scenes;
```

And I add a scene to it like this:

```
MainScene* mainscene; //I do not make it a new because i want my scenemanager to handle that
scenes.emplace("mainscene", mainscene); // add it to the list
```

and I have a function like this:

```
template <class T>
void SceneManager::recreateScene(T* &scene)
{
    scene = new T();
}
```

So that when I want to use a function `loadscene`, I can grab the scene from the list and delete the current scene and create the new scene with the function `recreateScene`. But the map gives me `Scene`. So when I use `recreateScene` it calls the constructor of `Scene()` instead of `MainScene()`. But I need it to know that the scene in the list is a `MainScene` so it creates a `new MainScene()` instead of a `new Scene()`.

Comment: Sounds like you need to have a virtual function in your Scene class and override it in every 'extending' class.

Comment: Mixing templates and runtime-polymorphism is always hard. While polymorphism has the intention of "forgetting" the special type templates need them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do that is to store the creator alongside the pointer. Something like this:

```
std::map<std::string, std::pair<Scene*, std::function<Scene*()>> scenes;

scenes.emplace("mainscene", {nullptr, []() { return new MainScene(); }});
```

Then, modify `recreateScene`:

```
template <class T>
void SceneManager::recreateScene(Scene* &scene, std::function<Scene*()> creator)
{
  scene = creator();
}

// called as:
auto& s = scenes["mainscene"];
recreateScene(s.first, s.second);
```

---

Side note: If these pointers own the `Scene` object, they should not be raw pointers, but `std::unique_ptr<Scene>` instead. DTTO for the return type of the `std::function`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple and efficient way to answer your needs is to implement a "*self-rebuild*" function in the following way :

```
class Scene {
    virtual ~Scene();
    virtual void self_rebuild() = 0;
};

class MainScene : public Scene {
    ~MainScene();
    void self_rebuild() {
        this->~MainScene();    // destroy scene (without deallocation)
        new(this) MainScene(); // rebuild a MainScene object in place (without reallocation)
    }
};
```

The main advantage of this method is to cleanup/rebuild the object without deallocation/reallocation. It is perfectly safe, as long as the object is the most derived object of class `MainScene`.

Reference to the standard (3.8/7) :

> If, after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or released, a new object is created at the storage location which the original object occupied, a pointer that pointed to the original object, a reference that referred to the original object, or the name of the original object will automatically refer to the new object and, once the lifetime of the new object has started, can be used to manipulate the new object, if:
>
> - the storage for the new object exactly overlays the storage
>   location which the original object occupied, and
> - the new object
>   is of the same type as the original object (ignoring the top-level
>   cv-qualifiers), and
> - the type of the original object is not
>   const-qualified, and, if a class type, does not contain any
>   non-static data member whose type is const-qualified or a reference
>   type, and
> - the original object was a most derived object (1.8) of
>   type T and the new object is a most derived object of type T (that
>   is, they are not base class subobjects).

Answer (score 0):

How about a pure virtual function on your Scene, called "clone" which returns a Scene*?  MainScene can then have something like `Scene* clone() {return new MainScene(*this);}`

Comment: this only works though if there was a `Scene*` to clone in the first place.

Comment: `"void SceneManager::recreateScene(T* &scene)"` The question states there is

Comment: `Scene* scene = nullptr; recreateScene(scene)` could also be valid in the question.

Comment: Sure - although that concept would break any design.  It would be like saying "I want to clone a class but don't know what class"

Comment: well that is what happens... storing an uninitialized `MainScene` pointer in a map of `Scene` pointers. I'm not saying your solution is bad. But with the information from what I see in the question this maybe has some limitations.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest letting the objects handle their own creation in a virtual function.  That way you won't need to track the type.

```
class Scene{
    Scene();
    virtual ~Scene();

    virtual Scene* ReCreate() = 0;
}

class MainScene : public Scene{
    MainScene();
    virtual ~MainScene();

    virtual Scene *ReCreate(){
        return new MainScene();
    }
}

template <class T>
void SceneManager::recreateScene(T* &scene){
    Scene *temp = scene;
    scene = scene->ReCreate();
    delete temp;
}
```